# Function as parameter for Module

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How is it possible to use a mathematical function as module- parameter

Such as:

```
PersonalPlot[fun0_, var0_, min0_, max0_] :=
 Module[{fun = fun0, var = var0 , min = min0, max = max0},

   (*this is incorrect*)
   fun = fun[var_];

   Plot[fun, {var, min, max}]
 ]

PersonalPlot[x^2,x,0,3];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, that statement is incorrect.  Mathematica evaluates it to something like

```
x^2[x]
```

when you call `PersonalPlot` and that evaluates to, well, in words to `x to the power of 2 of x` which doesn't make a lot of sense.  There are a number of ways round the problem.  The simplest would be to dispense with a Module altogether and define:

```
PersonalPlot1[fun0_, var0_, min0_, max0_] := Plot[fun0, {var0, min0, max0}]
```

which you would call like this:

```
PersonalPlot1[x^2, x, 0, 3]
```

Note that a call like this `PersonalPlot1[x^2, y, 0, 3]` produces an empty plot because the variable in the function passed in is not the same variable as the second argument.  Read on.

If you want to define a module which takes a function as an argument, then this is one way of doing it:

```
PersonalPlot2[fun0_, var0_, min0_, max0_] := 
 Module[{fun = fun0, var = var0, min = min0, max = max0},
  Plot[fun[var], {var, min, max}]]
```

which you would call like this

```
PersonalPlot2[#^2 &, x, 0, 3]
```

Note:

- The function passed into the function is a pure function.  If you are not already familiar with Mathematica's pure functions now would be a good time to consult the relevant parts of the documentation.
- This explicitly tells the `Plot` command to evaluate `fun[var]` over the range you specify.
- Your local variables are not strictly necessary since your function works by side-effect, producing a plot rather than manipulating (copies of) the arguments passed to it. You could rewrite this simply as:

  ```
  PersonalPlot2b[fun0_, var0_, min0_, max0_] := Module[{},
    Plot[fun0[var0], {var0, min0, max0}]]
  ```

Another possibility would be to drop the argument which represents the variable input to the function passed to `PersonalPlot`, like this:

```
PersonalPlot3[fun0_, min0_, max0_] := Module[{x},
  Plot[fun0[x], {x, min0, max0}]]
```

which you would call like this

```
PersonalPlot3[#^2 &, 0, 3]
```

In this version I've made `x` local to the `Module` to avoid clashes with any workspace variable also called `x`.  This avoids errors arising from using different names for the argument to the function (the pure function has no argument names) and the second argument to `PersonalPlot`; that has now been dropped.

There are probably several other useful ways of passing arguments to functions whether those functions use modules or not.

**EDIT**

Most of us who've used Mathematica for a while don't, I think, regard `#^2&` as something to avoid.  If you don't like it, you could use the more explicit syntax, like this:

```
fun1 = Function[x,x^2]
```

which you can then pass around like this

```
PersonalPlot[fun1,0.0,4.0]
```

By using this approach you can make your functions a bit less error prone by requiring the right types to be passed in, like this

```
PersonalPlot[fun_Function, min_Real, max_Real] := ...
```

but it's really up to you.

Off the top of my head I don't know how `Plot` does it, I'd have to look in the documentation.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for this magnificent -I would call it an- article. But the Problem is, that I don't really want to make a simple Plot but do some more operations... furthermore, the use of the module should be as easy as possible.. so isn't there a way around this `#^2 &`? thx

Comment: HPM, I wish you would post more often at Mathematica.SE.

Answer (score 0):

The following three examples may add to previous answer in illustrating some of the possible ways to pass functions as arguments.

Example 1: Though not an example of passing argument to a module, however tests passing a custom defined function to plot function, to get us started in passing functions to Plot functions, and the manner of invoking with argument [x]:

```
square[x_] := x^2/50;
fplot1[f_, x1_, x2_] := Plot[f, {x, x1, x2}]; 
fplot1[x^2/50, -2 Pi, 2 Pi]
fplot1[{square[x], Sin[x]}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi]
```

Example 2: In this example, the function name with argument is passed to the module, if x is not defined as a local variable. This is similar to passing a function to a Plot function. However, inside the module, only the function name without the argument is invoked:

```
fplot2[f_, x1_, x2_] := 
  Module [ (* 
   This type of function passing also works in Module so long as x is not defined as a local variable. *)
   {},
   Plot[f, {x, x1, x2}] 
   ];
fplot2[Sin[x], -2 Pi, 2 Pi] 
fplot2[{Sin[x], square[x]}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi]
```

Example 3: In this example, only the function name without argument is passed to the module, with x defined as a local variable.

```
fplot3[f_, x1_, x2_] := 
  Module [ (* This type of function passing works in Module with x declared as local variable. Only one function name can be passed. *)
   {x},
   Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}] 
   ];
fplot3[Sin, -2 Pi, 2 Pi] 
fplot3[square, -2 Pi, 2 Pi]
```

The last two examples illustrations of ready to use short examples that work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).